# How to fetch client's time in php(cake php / core)

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to fetch Client's time in cake php project to show records according to client's TimeZone.

Eg.

if in database created time of a Record is `4:03pm(16:03:00)` (India-Server time)

if client is in USA view the same record system must display `created time - 5:33` am(05:00:00)(according to the time zone of Washington)

Because when record was added by user in India

time was `4:03pm(16:03:00)` in india

and  `5:33` am(05:00:00)` in USA (Washington).

if possible post solutions by using cake php conventions, and if any user can solve my problem using core php, most welcome.

But not using javascript / jquery

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't allow the use of client side code, won't use IP address look up (which could be spoofed anyway) and won't allow the user to set the timezone (because of they might be wrong). So it seems the only acceptable solution is what HTTP provides, specifically the [HTTP request fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: Don't know why peoples are down voting, if there is no way to do this 
the way i want it. They can simply mention in comment. there is nothing wrong in this question either.

Comment: And for all the peoples who had down voted this question: "I got the solution, In Cake php we can do this by using Time helper".

Comment: Please explain how the time helper solves your problem since it has this caveat: _add a time zone field to your users table and make the necessary modifications to allow your users to set their time zone_ Somehow that data needs to be filled in and you did not want your users to do it.

Comment: I am using Cake php plugin here: http://www.ip2location.com/developers/cakephp and on github too https://github.com/ip2location/ip2location-cakephp  to find clients location/TimeZone and using this time zone in time helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But not using javascript / jquery

No, it is not. Except you force the user to configure his timezone in his user profile or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I can fetch user's time zone by using his IP with the help of googleAPI. but i don't want to hit a API because the function which includes this code runs every time when page refreshes.

Comment: and can't let user to fill time zone, because user can enter wrong TimeZone

Comment: You can't rely on the geolocation via IP either.

Comment: Thanks, I Got the solution, In Cake php it is possible by using Time Helper.

Comment: No, the helper does not know the TZ either... You need to pass a known TZ to it to convert it. Except you *assume* all your visitors are coming from a certain TZ. Getting the TZ from an user won't be accurate in any case. The most accurate TZ you can get is by let the user enter it. The only margin of error you have then is that he made a wrong click and didn't notice he selected the wrong TZ. Every other option is not more reliable.

Comment: I am using Cake php plugin here: http://www.ip2location.com/developers/cakephp  and on github too https://github.com/ip2location/ip2location-cakephp